# What's the best way to manage GUI states (create, edit, read modes...)

Tags: c#, java, .net, vb.net, user-interface

I was asked by a client to create a tool that would let a user add/modify/delete/read content from a database. The content can be read from TextBoxes.

My question is, what is the best way to manage GUI locks/unlocks for the different states of the program. IE: If I'm in a "insert" mode, some GUI elements should be enabled, and some not. If I'm in the "read-only" mode, a bunch of them should be disabled... etc.

Right now I've created some methods in my GUI Class, that should manage this. However, the states should be managed in similar ways I guess...

The program is currently developed in Java, but I've had this problem in .Net before.

Edit: As I can see, some people think this question is too general. I'm looking for patterns, techniques, etc...

Comment: you can use bool operator to maintain states like add and edit and save modes

Comment: sounds like the State design pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad.

There are many different approaches to maintain the visibility and enabled/disabled status of your controls in your GUI. As long as you are using .Net I would recommend looking at [Commands in WPF](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands): here you can bind the enabled property of your controls to `CanExecute` property of command and just maintain the availability of your commands -- your controls will automatically reflect the changes.

Comment: I'm not, but it's still a suggestion, and I appreciate it!